# Class Diagrams - Attribute Inheritance

Tags: class, model, uml, diagram

I need to inherit from a class and I only need to inherit selected attributes, is this possible or can you only inherit from classes if you need all of the attributes?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: It would be helpful to mention the programming language and the purpose of inheriting only selected attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for implementation inheritance rather than interface inheritance.   See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032359/game-engine-design-choise/4033303#4033303) for explanation, also note below if it's still not clear why.

Given that you're only looking to reuse a subset of the selected attributes you'd probably be better off using Composition instead of Inheritance.

**Note**

It can't be interface inheritance (subtyping) since, by only 'inheriting' a subset of attributes, a subclass instance would not be substitutable for a superclass instance.  For example: assume the superclass exposed property `A` that the subclass didn't inherit.  At run time, a variable `v` declared as the superclass type gets bound to an instance of the subclass.  An expression then references `v.A`.  Perfectly reasonable request - but it would obviously fail.  In other words, you broke the interface contract.  Google 'Liskov Substitution Principle' for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. When a superclass defines an attribute, any subclass can redefine the attribute to have [0..0] multiplicity. Thus, the subclass can inherit only what it needs. **However**, as @sfinnie mentioned, this breaks [Liskov Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), so you'd better know what you're doing!

A draft of the UML 2.5 spec I have handy says:

> A MultiplicityElement can define a multiplicity both of whose bounds are zero. This restricts the allowed cardinality to be 0; that is, it requires that an instantiation of this element contain no values. [...] It applies to (but is not limited to) redefining properties existing in more general Classifiers.